# Ruby Regex Help

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to Extract the Members Home sites links from a site. 
Looks like this

```
<a href="http://www.ptop.se" target="_blank">
```

i tested with it this site

http://www.rubular.com/

```
<a href="(.*?)" target="_blank">
```

Shall output http://www.ptop.se,

Here comes the code

```
    require 'open-uri'
    url = "http://itproffs.se/forumv2/showprofile.aspx?memid=2683"
    open(url) { |page| content = page.read()
    links = content.scan(/<a href="(.*?)" target="_blank">/)
    links.each {|link| puts #{link} 
    }
    }
```

if you run this, it dont works. why not?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you use one of the good ruby HTML/XML parsing libraries e.g. [Hpricot](http://wiki.github.com/why/hpricot) or [Nokogiri](http://wiki.github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri).

If you need to log in on the site you might be interested in a library like [WWW::Mechanize](http://rubyforge.org/projects/mechanize/).

Code example:

```
require "open-uri"
require "hpricot"
require "nokogiri"

url = "http://itproffs.se/forumv2"

# Using Hpricot 
doc = Hpricot(open(url))
doc.search("//a[@target='_blank']").each { |user| puts "found #{user.inner_html}" }

# Using Nokogiri
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
doc.xpath("//a[@target='_blank']").each { |user| puts "found #{user.text}" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Several issues with your code

2. I don't know what you mean by using

   ## {link}. But if you want to append a '#' character to the link make sure

   you wrap that with quotes. ie
   "#{link}"
3. String.scan accepts a block. Use it
   to loop through the matches.
4. The page you are trying to access
   does not return any links that the
   regex would match anyway.

Here's something that would work:

```
require 'open-uri'
url = "http://itproffs.se/forumv2/"
open(url) do |page|
    content = page.read()
    content.scan(/<a href="(.*?)" target="_blank">/) do |match|
            match.each { |link| puts link}
        end
end
```

There're better ways to do it, I am sure. But this should work.

Hope it helps

Comment: Your first point is not true.  You probably *should* use do/end for clarity, but multi-line blocks can use curly braces.

Comment: I did not know that. You're right. I apologize for the misinformation. Corrected.